# unable to upgrade or install nodejs

Tags: node.js

When I am trying to install nodejs I am getting following message

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,701 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 503726 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nodejs (from .../nodejs_0.10.29-1chl1~saucy1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up nodejs (0.10.29-1chl1~saucy1) ...

and when I run  `node -v`
it say node note present at

```
bash: /home/<username>/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

Comment: As Robert Rossmann said, on Ubuntu the executable is named `nodejs`. What's the output of the commands: `which nodejs` and `type nodejs` ?

Answer (score 2):

The interpreter for Ubuntu is called `nodejs`, not just `node`.

See the [list of files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/nodejs/filelist) contained in this package.

This is due to a conflict with a historically older (I think) package, [Amateur Packet Radio Node program](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/node), which includes the `node` executable.

If you would like to use the `node` executable, and you do not need the conflicting package to be installed, simply create a symlink anywhere appropriate, i.e. in */usr/local/bin*:

```
[sudo] ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using NVM especially on Ubuntu due to the naming kafuffle as mentioned by @robert rossman